# Using optionsMenu programmatically

Tags: android

I'm aware that you can display the options menu by using openOptionsMenu() method, but this only works if the options menu was previously created(by clicking before the menu hardkey), so my question is: Is there any way of creating the optionsMenu for opening it without having to hit the menu hard key?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the method `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.